# react-native-webview UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME error on Android only?

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

- react-native: `0.59.8`
- react-native-webview: `0.11.5`

I have a very simple webview.

```js
<WebView
  source={{ uri: authZeroUrl(authMode, nonce) }}
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  onNavigationStateChange={response => checkForToken(response)}
/>
```

But when a response comes back on Android I get the following error.
It works without issue on iOS.

```
WebView error: , Object {
  "canGoBack": false,
  "canGoForward": false,
  "code": -10,
  "description": "net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME",
  "loading": false,
  "target": 105,
  "title": "Sign In with Auth0",
  "url": "exp://tv-7as.awesomelabs.awesome-chat-app.exp.direct:80/redirect#access_token=RqaE{more stuff after this}
```

Because it works in iOS maybe it has something to do with the native side of the code?
I'm not exactly sure how to troubleshoot this issue. Any ideas would be super helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Is url's address https?

Comment: No, it's an app url. `exp:` It's the callback after logging in.